# Angular: JWT renewal with NgRx effect

Tags: angular, jwt, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I would like to adapt [this code](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs/05-token-renewal) for an Angular project, using NgRx effect to handle JWT renewal. But I get stuck with observables, since token is only renewed once because `timer` completes at first time. I also tried with the `delay` operator but since it does not create an observable, I don't know how to implement it in this stream. Any thoughts? Thanx!

```
// auth.effects.ts

@Effect()
renewJWT$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionTypes.RenewJWT),
  filter(() => this.authService.isLoggedIn()),
  concatMap(() =>
    this.authService.renewJWT().pipe(
      map(() => new ScheduleJWTRenewalAction())
    )
  )
);

@Effect()
scheduleJWTRenewal$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(
    ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT,
    ActionTypes.SigninSuccess,
    ActionTypes.ScheduleJWTRenewal
  ),
  takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(ActionTypes.Logout))),
  map(() => Date.parse(this.authService.session.expiresAt) - Date.now()),
  filter((remainingTime: number) => remainingTime > 0),
  concatMap((remainingTime: number) =>
    timer(Math.max(remainingTime, 1)).pipe(
      map(() => new RenewJWTAction())
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: why don't you keep the principe of using setTimeout which could dispatch a specific action to renew (or check expiration) of token.

Answer (score 0):

**timer**

> signature: timer(initialDelay: number | Date, period: number,
>   scheduler: Scheduler): Observable
>
> After given duration, emit numbers in sequence every specified
>   duration.

If `period` was not specified `timer` will emit once and complete.

```
takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(ActionTypes.Logout))),
```

After user logout `scheduleJWTRenewal$` stream will complete. Is it possible to user to login again? ) .

It will be better to replace `takeUntil` on `filter`.